# Gnome terminal prints broken characters with packet sniffer

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

I have written a basic network packet sniffer with Python. When the packets comes, the program prints broken characters in my gnome-terminal.
Program codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import struct
import binascii

s = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 8)
i = 1

while True:
    pkt  = s.recvfrom(2048)
    ethhead = pkt[0][0:14] 
    eth = struct.unpack("!6s6s2s",ethhead)

    print "--------Ethernet Frame %d------" % i
    print "Destination MAC: ", binascii.hexlify(eth[0]) 
    print "Source MAC: ", binascii.hexlify(eth[1])
    binascii.hexlify(eth[2])

    ipheader = pkt[0][14:34]    #next 20 bytes  
    ip_hdr = struct.unpack("!8sB3s4s4s",ipheader)
    print "-----------IP------------------"
    print "TTL :", ip_hdr[1]
    print "Source IP", socket.inet_ntoa(ip_hdr[3])
    print "Destination IP", socket.inet_ntoa(ip_hdr[4])  

    tcpheader = pkt[0][34:54]   #extracts next 20 bytes
    tcp_hdr = struct.unpack("!HH9ss6s",tcpheader)    
    print "---------TCP----------"
    print "Source Port ", tcp_hdr[0]
    print "Destination port ", tcp_hdr[1]
    print "Flag ",binascii.hexlify(tcp_hdr[3])

    print "\n\n"
    i += 1
    print pkt[0][54:]
```

The sample output:

[Sample Output Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nnd849txs0xvtc/s.png?dl=0)

I had set Terminal>Set character Encoding>Unicode(UTF-8) but it did not work either.

I am using Kali Linux 1.1.0, Gnome Terminal v 3.4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Unfotunately, many protocols such as SSH and HTTPS use encryption and show characters that don't exist in ASCII or UTF-8. Your terminal will not be able to show these. This is because things like passwords and data should be hidden so that people can't do MITM nearly as easily. Try Wireshark, a graphical packet sniffer, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Bytes in the range 128-255 do not generally form valid UTF-8 strings. Even if the payload is encoded in UTF-8, there is no guarantee that packet boundaries will coincide with code point boundaries.

Perhaps as a workaround you would like to render the packets as e.g. ISO-8859-1 strings, or maybe even (gasp) offer an option to specify an encoding. The only change you need is `pkt[0][54:].decode(encoding)` - if there ever is a packet containing only complete, valid UTF-8 sequences, mentally decoding it from this output should be possible with a bit of training.